# How should I send a trajectory to an Arduino Robot Arm?

Tags: rviz, moveit, follow-joint-trajectory, actionlib, action-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have a Python action server running that gets the planned trajectory from MoveIt and it has to send the trajectory to the real robot - an Arduino Braccio. I found a way to parse the positions in the trajectory and send them one by one to Braccio but it moves in a very clumsy way, stopping between commands. What I want to do is make it move smoothly from the initial position until the goal position along the trajectory received by MoveIt. Here is the code I have so far: [braccio_controller.py](https://pastebin.com/6UwVYAtq). It uses this other Python script: [moving_braccio_pc.py](https://pastebin.com/ymVv1M6J)

Can someone point me what the correct way of giving such commands is?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267057/how-should-i-send-a-trajectory-to-an-arduino-robot-arm?/) by [BourbonCreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/31269/bourboncreams/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2017-07-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JayNewman](https://answers.ros.org/users/30899/jaynewman/) on 2017-07-22**:
This is just a thought but is the path sent to the robot as a group, or is each portion of the path sent one at a time until the Arduino robot requests the next portion?

**Comment by [JayNewman](https://answers.ros.org/users/30899/jaynewman/) on 2017-07-22**:
Another possible point of failure is the Arduino robot itself. Have you tried calculating a smooth path in ROS and then manually compiling this path into your Arduino robot with it disconnected from ROS?

**Comment by [BourbonCreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/31269/bourboncreams/) on 2017-07-26**:
Hi Jay, first of all the robot wasn't the issue because yes, I did try to execute a trajectory outside of ROS and it worked just fine.
I was previously sending each portion of the path separately but you gave me the idea of trying to send all of it and the execute it. This worked! Thank you

**Comment by [pranavb104](https://answers.ros.org/users/38753/pranavb104/) on 2018-12-27**:
Hi ! Im having the same problem for my custom robotic arm. How do u send all the values at once and receive and decode it at the arduino end? Let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After JayNewman's comment I tried sending the entire trajectory to the Arduino so that I could store it and then execute it once I received it all. Even though the communication between the two processors (Arduino side and Linux side, both on the board - using Bridge) is quite slow, the trajectory eventually makes it to the Arduino side which then executes the trajectory smoothly.

---

Originally posted by [BourbonCreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/31269/bourboncreams/) with karma: 18 on 2017-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pranavb104](https://answers.ros.org/users/38753/pranavb104/) on 2018-12-27**:
Hi ! Im having the same problem for my custom robotic arm. How do u send all the values at once and receive and decode it at the arduino end? Let me know!

**Comment by [BourbonCreams](https://answers.ros.org/users/31269/bourboncreams/) on 2018-12-28**:
Hi there, have a look at my Github repo for this project: https://github.com/BourbonCreams/braccio_arm

**Comment by [pranavb104](https://answers.ros.org/users/38753/pranavb104/) on 2018-12-28**:
Thanks! I got to know how to do it!